# yuv.compressToJpeg does not accept ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: android, arrays, android-camera, jpeg, bytearrayoutputstream

I am trying to convert the byte [] data that I am receiving in onPreviewFrame to jpeg using the following code.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, previewWidth, previewHeight, null);
yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, previewWidth, previewHeight), 0, baos);
....
```

but I am getting this error saying that

"The method compressToJpeg(Rect, int, OutputStream) in the type YuvImage is not applicable for the arguments (Rect, int, ByteArrayOutputStream)"

I have seen a lot of code in the web using the ByteArrayOutputStream. I have no idea why I am getting this error. Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using opencv or another library which also has Rect defined.
Use android.graphics.Rect instead of Rect.

Regards